# Overwriting close function of pyqtgraph application

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Wanting to visualize realtime data I wanted to use pyqtgraph since it can handle faster streams than matplotlib with less effort.
I started with following one of its basic examples and added a Thread that reads from a UDP signal to update the data that is plotted every 50ms. The code should work (provided another process is sending data to this UDP port) but the problem starts when the plotting application is closed.

I searched for the problem, and my guess is that when the application is closed, it first waits on all its processes to finish (so also for the thread to finish). But since the deamon thread only closes when the parent program closes, they both wait on each other.
I wanted to overwrite the close function of the plotting app to first close the thread before waiting on the rest to exit, but I could not find how to do that.

help would be very welcome.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore

import queue
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

import socket
from threading import Thread
import struct

class StreamReader(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.insocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.insocket.bind(('localhost', 54654))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            dat, _ = self.insocket.recvfrom(1000)
            val = struct.unpack('!f', dat)
            self.queue.put(val)

app = pg.mkQApp("plot datastream")
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="UDP datastream")
win.resize(1000,600)
win.setWindowTitle("PoC real-time graph")

pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

p1 = win.addPlot(title="real-time plot")
curve = p1.plot(pen="y")

q = queue.Queue()
sr = StreamReader(q)
sr.deamon=True
sr.start()
data = np.zeros(1000)
ptr=0
def update():
    global curve, data, ptr, p1
    while not q.empty():
        newval = q.get()
        data = np.append(data, newval)
    if data.size > 1000:
        data = data[-1000:]
    curve.setData(data)
    ptr += 1

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pg.mkQApp().exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the the line

```
dat, _ = self.insocket.recvfrom(1000)
```

was still blocking. So the problem was solved by adding the line

```
self.insocket.setblocking(0)
```

in the initialization of the class, and wrapping the lines in the while-loop in a try-except block, passing on the BlockingIOError.